# how to use marshmallow post_load? no attribute 'data'

Tags: python-3.x, marshmallow, flask-restplus

From [the docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) under 'Deserializing to Objects':

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load


class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    created_at = fields.DateTime()

    @post_load
    def make_user(self, data, **kwargs):
        return User(**data)
```

But I when I run this code, I get: 
`AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'data'`

What am I missing?

Comment: This code looks good to me. Please provide a complete example. Also please specify which marshmallow version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the data dictionary instead of an instance of your model.

I stumbled upon issue this while using `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` and `flask-marshmallow`

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load


class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    email = fields.Email()
    created_at = fields.DateTime()

    @post_load
    def make_user(self, data, **kwargs):
        data['extra_attribute'] = 'extra value'
        return data
```